# If column has matching string, write new string to new column

Tags: r

Trying to use Column A to isolate the phone brand and then print the brand to a new column Brand.

Original:

```
   Phone
Samsung note
Samsung note
Nokia lumia
Sony xperia
```

Desired:

```
   Phone          Brand
Samsung note 3   Samsung
Samsung note 4   Samsung
Nokia lumia       Nokia
Sony xperia       Sony
```

Problem I'm running into is: 1) i don't know how to create a the 'Brand' column with a specific string with the condition that the 'Phone' column has a specific string 2)while doing this for multiple brands and having the 'Brand' column reflect that.

What is the most elegant way to do this? 
And is there a dplyr method to do this using mutate?

Comment: In the expected output the 'Phone' column inserted numbers 3 and 4.  Is it a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done using `base R`.  We can use `sub` to remove part of the substring in 'Phone' column.  We match one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by 0 or more characters (`.*`) until the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with `''`.

```
df1$Brand <- sub('\\s+.*$', '', df1$Phone)
df1
#         Phone   Brand
#1 Samsung note Samsung
#2 Samsung note Samsung
#3  Nokia lumia   Nokia
#4  Sony xperia    Sony
```

---

Or another option is `extract` from `library(tidyr)`.  But, I would use `extract` only if we need to split a column into multiple columns.  In this case, we are keeping the original column and creating only a single new column.

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, Phone, into= 'Brand', '([^ ]+).*', remove=FALSE)
#         Phone   Brand
#1 Samsung note Samsung
#2 Samsung note Samsung
#3  Nokia lumia   Nokia
#4  Sony xperia    Sony
```

---

UPDATE: As mentioned in the comments, suppose if we have strings such as 'Samsungnote' or 'Nokialumina', one option would be `split/unsplit` by a grouping variable created based on the minimum number of characters after the `sub` step.  We use `substr` to extract the prefix part of the string, `split` by that, and then remove the suffix in each `list` element based on the number of characters, and `unsplit`.

```
v1 <-  sub('\\s+.*$', '', df2$Phone)
gr <- substr(v1, 1, min(nchar(v1)))
lst <- split(v1, gr)
df2$Brand <- unsplit(lapply(lst, function(x) substr(x, 1, min(nchar(x)))), gr)
df2
#         Phone   Brand
#1 Samsung note Samsung
#2 Samsung note Samsung
#3  Nokia lumia   Nokia
#4  Sony xperia    Sony
#5  Samsungnote Samsung
#6   Nokialumia   Nokia
```

NOTE: This may not work in all cases.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Phone = c("Samsung note", "Samsung note", 
"Nokia lumia", 
"Sony xperia")), .Names = "Phone", class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(Phone = c("Samsung note", "Samsung note", 
"Nokia lumia", 
"Sony xperia", "Samsungnote", "Nokialumia")), .Names = "Phone", 
class =  "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: your option with tidyr is better

Comment: Thanks great answer. Just for my own reference... what if the Phone column didn't have spaces in between the brand and phone model. 'Samsung note' -> 'Samsungnote'.

Comment: @ant It will be read as a single word.  If you have a list of all the phone brands, we can remove the suffix part hanging using `gsub` or so.  Otherwise, regex won't recognise i..e `sub('(Samsung).*', '\\1', 'Samsungnote')`

Answer (score 2):

If you have several elements in each rows of your column phone, you can use `cSplit` from package `splitstackshape`:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cbind(df1, cSplit(df1, 'Phone', sep=' ')[,1, with=F])
#           Phone Phone_1
#1 Samsung note 3 Samsung
#2 Samsung note 4 Samsung
#3    Nokia lumia   Nokia
#4    Sony xperia    Sony
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Phone = c("Samsung note 3", "Samsung note 4", "Nokia lumia", 
"Sony xperia")), .Names = "Phone", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```